# How can I display a name in a different sequence using strings?

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm having trouble with a problem that I was assigned for my Visual Basic 2012 class. The instructions are below. So far, I have it displaying only the first name entered, and nothing else. How can I make it to display both the first name and the last name in the sequence requested?

> **String Problem:** Enter your first and last name in a text box. Take the name and display it in a label box showing the last name, first name.

Text Box Entry: Jane Doe

Label Box: Doe, Jane

The code I have so far is below. Thanks for any help!

```
Private Sub btndisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndisplay.Click
    Dim fullname As String
    Dim firstname As String
    Dim indexnum As Integer
    Dim lastname As String

    fullname = fulltextbox.Text

    indexnum = fullname.IndexOf(" ")

    firstname = fullname.Substring(0, indexnum)

    firstlabel.Text = firstname
    fulltextbox.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub fulltextbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    firstlabel.Text = String.Empty

    fulltextbox.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub btnexit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Should the label change when you click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track by first determining where the space is located:

```
indexnum = fullname.IndexOf(" ")
```

Now based on this index, you can split the string into two strings, `firstname` and `lastname`:

```
firstname = fullname.Substring(0, indexnum)
lastname = fullname.Substring(indexnum+1)
```

You need to use `indexnum+1`, instead of `indexnum`, otherwise you will include the spacing character.

Finally you group them together again by using the [*string concatenation* operator (`&`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx):

```
firstlabel.Text = lastname & ", " & firstname
```

---

The final method thus looks like:

```
Private Sub btndisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndisplay.Click
    Dim fullname As String
    Dim firstname As String
    Dim indexnum As Integer
    Dim lastname As String

    fullname = fulltextbox.Text

    indexnum = fullname.IndexOf(" ")

    firstname = fullname.Substring(0, indexnum)
    lastname = fullname.Substring(indexnum+1)

    firstlabel.Text = lastname & ", " & firstname
    fulltextbox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, this won't work if your using middle initials. Also, I would remove `fulltextbox.SelectAll()` from `fulltextbox_TextChanged`

```
Private Sub btndisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndisplay.Click

    Dim Names() As String = fulltextbox.Text.Split(" "c)

    If Names.Count = 2 Then
        firstlabel.Text = Names(1) + ", " + Names(0)
    ElseIf Names.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter name.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Nmae entered.")
    End If

    fulltextbox.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: This one didn't work because Option Strict On disallows implicit conversations from String to Char, but thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I fixed it. `Dim Names() As String = fulltextbox.Text.Split(" "c)
`